# JSON Parsing error and Responsive Calendar

Tags: javascript, json, calendar

I have a problem passing events to Responsive calendar (http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/). I try to create a simple object with a calendar date. For your convenience I simplified the script to the following:

```
 /* Create calendar events object*/

 appointment="2014-01-25"; 
 var options={"badgeClass":"badge-warning", "url": ""};

 var str = "{'" + appointment + "':{'badgeClass':'badge-warning'}}";
 var test2=JSON.parse(str);

 /* Initialize calendar */
  $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
  time: '2014-01',
  events: test2
  });
```

If I use

```
var test={'2014-04-25': options};
```

the calendar highlights the specified date. Nevertheless, the parsed string produces an "Unexpected token ' " error. I couldn't think of a better way to create the object, since I get the dates dynamically. Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this is useful to anyone, the problem was double quotes.
The correct syntax is

```
 var str = '{"' + appointment + '":{"badgeClass":"badge-warning"}}';
```